# jQuery Mobile Page Navigation

Tags: jquery, mobile, navigation

I've 4 pages in my web project say a,b,c & d. Each page has a tab-bar/navigation bar at top and buttons which are  and linked to each other. The navigation works perfect.
However, I want to perform some actions like, when b is clicked - some data will be fetched from database, when c is clicked data is updated and likewise. However, all these javascript functions works on first page which gets started when web-app is executed. If I navigate to other pages, js on that page doesn't work. Can't we have once for all binding to all these buttons?
Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: You should further elaborate!

Answer (score 2):

jquerymobile will try to use Ajax to retrieve page content and add to current page DOM instead of normal page request by default. You may try following options:
1. Use $.mobile.changePage()
2. Use mobileinit event (before jquerymobile js loaded) to change the default behavior:
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;  //do not handle links via ajax by default
});